# Entity Framework: unidirectional navigation with data annotation

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have to model 2 entities: Book and Label. Book class contains book information and the reference to Label class which contains a label text. I have therefore to realize a one way navigation from Book class to Label class because when I visualize a book entity I would like to read the Label value, but when I visualize a Label I don't want to have any information about Book.

I have found a lot of examples with Fluent API but I need to realize with Data Annotations. Any ideas?

```
public class Book
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    //What about label? How to navigate from Book to Label?

}

public class Label
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any annotations, EntityFramework follows conventions, just add a property in the `Book` of type `Label` and the same for the other class, just like this:

```
public class Book
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public Label Label {get;set;}

}

public class Label
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Book Book { get; set; }
}
```